# java Array contains object

Tags: java, indexof

I have

```
String selectedName = "ABC";
List<object> pgetName;
```

where object has variables such as *id, name, version*

I want to do the equivalent of

```
int first = pgetName.indexOf(selectedName);
int last = pgetName.lastIndexOf(selectedName);
```

as used for simple String Arrays.  I've tried

```
int first = pgetName.getProperty("name").indexOf(processToStart);
```

and

```
int first = pgetName[].getName().indexOf(processToStart);
```

for example but they don't work. How do I do what I want to do?  This is advanced Java for me being a noob...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean "they don't work"? What is your expected vs actual outcome?

Comment: You will need a loop. And for every element check if it matches.

Comment: `List<object> pgetName` Are you asking about Lists or arrays?

Comment: @reggaeguitar, I was hoping it would return me the index points to the first and last elements in the list where pgetName.name() = "ABC";

Comment: @martijnn2008, thanks I was hoping not to do that...

Comment: @Radiodef, it's a list, I was using String Array as an example of what I want to do.

Comment: Why were you hoping not to use a loop? Any library method will use a loop (unless the list is sorted then it could use binary search instead).

Comment: The library I thought would be better at it than I for performance,  and I have to go into a two further nested loops.  I was looking to short cut the first at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an other approach (might be a little overkill but it shows you an other way).  The idea is to override the indexOf and lastIndexOf method so it would verify against your field "name":

```
    private static class TestObject {

    String id, name, version;

    public TestObject(String id, String name, String version) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<TestObject> pgetName = new ArrayList<TestObject>() {
        @Override
        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            if (o == null || this.isEmpty()) {
                return -1;
            }
            int counter=0;
            for (TestObject current : this) {
                if (o.equals(current.getName())) {
                    return counter;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
            if (o == null || this.isEmpty()) {
                return -1;
            }
            for (int i=this.size()-1; i>=0;i--) {
                TestObject current = get(i);
                if (o.equals(current.getName())) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    };
    pgetName.add(new TestObject("1", "name1", "ver1"));
    pgetName.add(new TestObject("2", "name2", "ver2"));
    pgetName.add(new TestObject("3", "name3", "ver3"));
    pgetName.add(new TestObject("4", "name1", "ver4"));
    int first = pgetName.indexOf("name1");
    int last = pgetName.lastIndexOf("name1");
    System.out.println("First: " + first + " - Last: " + last);

}
```

Result is:

```
First: 0 - Last: 3
```

Comment: Marked as correct as it meets my requirements completely.  Many thanks and festive greetings.

Answer (score 1):

For any Java object you can override the methods equals and hashCode (this is not really used but it is generally a good practice to implement both methods) in order to use the indexOf and lastIndexOf functions of java.util.List.

The contextual menu of eclipse generates a default implementation of both methods, letting you choose on which field the comparison should be done. Give it a try.

After the implementation of the methods above, you can use indexOf on List.

Comment: He probably just wants a HashMap<String, Object>, keyed off the name value unless there's some particular reason he needs the index.  I suspect he doesn't.

Comment: Ok, didn't understand.

Comment: @spudone The List is pulled from a third party piece of software, and only comes as an ordered List, HashMap and Map could work but that would require conversion and would be performance suicide.

Comment: It would be faster to copy it to a HashMap once, then do lookups, versus looping through it for *every* lookup.  Just an option.

Comment: Appreciate the thought, the final List will have > 3000 entries, can't be saved in memory (not my forte and using Tomcat for this code) and can be updated every few minutes.  My reading of it could be anywhere between 1 every second to 1 per minute...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to "find the index of an Object where one of the properties of the object is a specific value".

This isn't directly possible in Java (or most languages FWIW).   You can achieve it pretty simply with a for loop, however:

```
public MyObject findObjectByName(MyObject[] objects, String name) {
    for (MyObject object: objects) {
       if (object.name.equal(name) {
          return object;
       }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you want to find the index, you can do something similar:

```
public int  findObjectIndex(MyObject[] objects, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i)
       if (objects[i].name.equal(name) {
          return i;
       }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Now, this is the most naive approach you can take, and is often, but not always, the best approach.  If you have a large number of objects, and you need to look up a lot by name, then you could be better off building an index once, and then look them up by the index:

```
public class MyObjectIndex {
   final Map<String, MyObject> byName = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
   public MyObjectIndex(MyObject[] objects) {
       for (MyObject object: objects) {
          byName.put(object.getName(), object);
       }
   }

   public getMyObjectWithName(String name) {
       return byName.get(name);
   }
}
```